# Give back item drop for map

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to create a command to detect the drop of an item and to give it back. That's the part where I struggle because I Don't how to say that this item is this so "give it back".

Comment: By teleporting the item to the player? Or do you want anything else, like putting it into the same slot again or whatever? I don't really see where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other items floating around in the map, you can use a command block. Set it to repeat and always active. In the command block, you can use this command:
`/tp @e[type=Item] [player]`
This will take a moment for the item to be picked back up. If you want it to be a specific item, you can use the command `/tp @e[type=item,name="name of item in lang"] @p`. In the second command, you have to use the name that is displayed in-game, not the Minecraft ID. This will also take a moment for the item to be picked back up.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the data from the items that are dropped and change their PickupDelay to 0s (that is the amount of time needed to be able to get picked up by a player), so the command would be like this:

```
/execute as @e[type=item] run data modify entity @s PickupDelay set value 0s
```

Set this on a repeat commandblock and it will work for any item. Also if you only want to change for a specific item, then you'll need to change a bit of the selectors on the @e brackets.